# How do I get enumerate the PropertyGroup elements in a csproj file from powershell

Tags: powershell, nuget, envdte

I'm writing a nuget install script in powershell and I want to access to all the PropertyGroup elements of the project file (*.csproj)?

I have access to a variable called $project which represents an object, I believe it to implement the Project interface from [EnvDTE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.project.aspx) - an abstraction of the project file (*.csproj).

How does I get the PropertyGroup instances from the $project object?

I want the ability from the nuget install powershell script to change the 
OutputPath for all PropertyGroup elements that contain this child element.

Comment: Some people can have issues with questions that contain no code. I know PowerShell but dont know your environment or nuget so it would be impossible to help you without more information. A DV and VTC should just be a bump in the road. Nothing that justifies that comment though.

Comment: I didnt cast either of the votes FYI I was just trying to potentially explain the action of the one who did. I am keeping out of this

Comment: FWIW, the question contained enough information for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PropertyGroup is an internal implementation (MSBuild technology) of the .csproj file, and EnvDTE.Project is an interface, so with EnvDTE.Project you can't get or modify *directly* the MSBuild elements, because in fact before VS 2005 the .csproj was not MSBuild-based and the EnvDTE.Project interface already existed and worked with the previous technology.

But being an interface, you can certainly do your task:

The OutputPath is a property of each project configuration. You can get all the configurations of an EnvDTE.Project as explained in:

[HOWTO: Get the projects configurations / platforms from a Visual Studio add-in](http://www.visualstudioextensibility.com/articles/add-ins/)

(add-ins use EnvDTE)

and once you have an EnvDTE.Configuration, you can access its EnvDTE.Configuration.Properties collection and specifically the "OutputPath". See:

[HOWTO: Get the output build folder from a Visual Studio add-in or macro](http://www.visualstudioextensibility.com/articles/add-ins/)

Once all the project configurations are changed, you can call [EnvDTE.Project.Save](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.project.save.aspx) or [EnvDTE.Project.SaveAs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.project.saveas.aspx) passing the [EnvDTE.Project.FullName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.project.fullname.aspx) value as parameter.

Comment: thanks for such a detailed answer, I'll up vote when I've tried the solutions provided

Comment: What a great set of articles, managed to work out what I wanted thanks

Comment: It seems that you answered yourself

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer which led me to the solution: [Transforming .csproj using nuget package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35017029/transforming-csproj-using-nuget-package/35021391#35021391)

Here is the script I used in the NuGet package:

```
$msbuild = [Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection]::GlobalProjectCollection.GetLoadedProjects($project.FullName) | Select-Object -First 1
($msbuild.Xml.PropertyGroups | Select-Object -First 1).AddProperty("TypeScriptCompileBlocked", "true")
$project.Save()
```